# I am running to some kind of errors SAYING This expression is typed incorrectly, or it's too complex to be evaluated

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT T.NAME AS Expr1, T.AREA AS Expr2, T.AlarmCount, 
       CDate(Format(T.[ITIME],"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")) AS ITIME, 
       CDate(Format(T.ATIME,"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")) AS ATIME, 
       CDate(Format(T.NTIME,"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")) AS NTIME, T.DUR AS Expr3
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT(IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME) AS NAME, 
              COUNT(*) AS AlarmCount,
              IWTUSER_ALARMS.AREA AS AREA, 
              IWTUSER_ALARMS.ITIME AS ITIME, 
              IWTUSER_ALARMS.ATIME AS ATIME, 
              IWTUSER_ALARMS.NTIME AS NTIME,
              IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR AS DURATION
     FROM IWTUSER_ALARMS
     GROUP BY IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME, 
                      IWTUSER_ALARMS.AREA, 
                    ITIME,                  
                    ATIME, 
                    NTIME, 
                    IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR

    )  AS T
WHERE (((CDate(Format([IWTUSER_ALARMS].[ITIME],"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")))>=Date()-180));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT T.NAME AS Expr1, T.AREA AS Expr2, T.AlarmCount,
  Format([T].[ITIME],"General Date") AS ITIME,
  Format(T.ATIME,"General Date") AS ATIME,
  Format(T.NTIME,"General Date") AS NTIME,
  T.DURATION AS Expr3
FROM (SELECT  DISTINCT(IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME) AS NAME, 
          COUNT(*) AS AlarmCount,
          IWTUSER_ALARMS.AREA AS AREA, 
          IWTUSER_ALARMS.ITIME AS ITIME, 
          IWTUSER_ALARMS.ATIME AS ATIME, 
          IWTUSER_ALARMS.NTIME AS NTIME,
          IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR AS DURATION
 FROM IWTUSER_ALARMS
 GROUP BY IWTUSER_ALARMS.NAME, 
                  IWTUSER_ALARMS.AREA, 
                ITIME,                  
                ATIME, 
                NTIME, 
                IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR
)  AS T
WHERE (((T.ITIME)>=Date()-180));
```

The error was caused by your `WHERE` clause. `ITIME` is already a date, so you can compare it without formating to string (with wrong format expression) and then revert to a date with an invalid date and `ITIME` comes from temp table `T` not `IWTUSER_ALARMS` in `WHERE`clause.

`IWTUSER_ALARMS.DUR AS DURATION` has alias `DURATION`.

Your date format is wrong. Try `Debug.Print Format(#6/18/2016#,"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00 ")`. This is how to format date http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php.

`ITIMES, ATIME and NTIME`should be displayed as string, I assume or delete the format (see `WHERE` clause error).

Avoid reserved keywords like `NAME` in variables and identifiers. Hope I catched them all!

Comment: Thank you for all your help - now I don't get an overflow error but no data is displaying for some reason. I even played around with the dates between 1 day and last 30 days nothing is showing on the datasheet.